# Mechanize visit a link and get page title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

I am using mechanize to scrape some data. Unfortunately I can't seem to get it to visit the link and get the page title of the visited page.

here is my task:

```
task :estimateone => :environment do
  require 'mechanize'

  mechanize = Mechanize.new
  page = mechanize.get('https://www.city.com/city/list/50-city-cafes-you-should-have-eaten-breakfast-at')
  page.css('ol li a').each do |link|
   mechanize.click(link).each do |property|
        puts property.title
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clicking on the link, you don't need the block, you're already in a block, iterating over each anchor you found in your "main" URL.

If you click any link, it returns you the page it points to (anchor's href). You can see this inspecting what's on your mechanize variable after that:

```
page.css(<selector>).each do |link|
  mechanize.click(link)
  mechanize

=> #<Mechanize
 ...
 #<Mechanize::Page
  {url #<URI::HTTPS https://www.theurbanlist.com/brisbane/directory/scout-cafe>}
  {meta_refresh}
  {title "Scout Cafe, Petrie Terrace | Brisbane | The Urban List"}
  {iframes
```

There you are. Mechanize handles for you now the data belonging to the current page. So now you're able to, through mechanize, using its `page` method, access its title and all others:

```
page.css('div[itemprop="articleBody"] ol li a').each do |link|
  mechanize.click(link)
  puts "Title: #{mechanize.page.title}"
end

Title: Scout Cafe, Petrie Terrace | Brisbane | The Urban List
Title: Southside Tea Room | Brisbane | The Urban List
Title: Spring Hill Deli Cafe, Spring Hill | Brisbane | The Urban List
```

Notice the use of the itemprop attribute isn't really needed, but I recommend you to add more specific CSS rules/selectors to make the elements easy to recognize.